# How to set required fields and default values for work items

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for my project, and accessing it via the web. I am using the Scrum template.

I am trying to figure out how to set default values for Task fields. For example, for the task's Activity field, I want to make it a required field, and set the default value to "Development" whenever I add a new task.

How can I do this?

Comment: You've tagged both VSTS  as well as TFS, which one are you using (cloud or on premise)? And which version at that?

Comment: Good question. I'm very new at this. I'm using the MS cloud, not my own server. Not sure about version, if that's even relevant if it's cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TFS

On TFS you need to customize the process template to provide a `<DEFAULT>` rule. To change the process template you need to use `witadmin` to export the workitem type definition you want to change, then edit the XML to add the rule you want, in your case a `<DEFAULT>` rule on the transition to the default state. The re-import the workitem type definition.

The process/rules are explained here:

- [Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194948.aspx)
- [Modify or add a custom work item type (WIT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx)

### VS-Team-Services

On Visual Studio Team Services this option does not exist yet for system fields. The features for process customization have been released in the past months and are rapidly evolving. It's probably a short wait until these features will be available.

What you can do is use the "Template" link on the work item form to create a bookmark that will open the work item form with a number of fields pre-filled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. On the Template link solution, how would that work if I'm adding a task for a specific backlog item? Currently, I go to the Backlog item and click the + sign to add a task to the backlog item. If I'm using a bookmark to get to the work item window instead of the + sign, how will it know what backlog item it add it to?

Comment: Too bad in that case.