# How do I make all fields in template mandatory in TFS?

Tags: azure, testing, tfs

As a tester I have created a template using queries in TFS which runs with Azure, so now I can simply raise a bug choose the template and fill it in.

How do I make all fields mandatory so we don't miss any vital information?

Comment: You might want to clarify TFS, AzureDevOps, On-Prem or hosted? This same question is a bit old now and things have probably changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924998/how-to-set-required-fields-and-default-values-for-work-items - although I think Jesse is right and you need a DEFAULT rule as described in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-field?view=azure-devops-2019

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, have read your post and docs but as a newbie I am would it be possible in your experience to give me step by step instructions in how to simply put all fields mandatory in the bug raised template? Oh its hosted by the way

Comment: @Tom Do you mean you are using Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx), and want to have all fields mandatory in Bug work item? Do you use [inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) or [Hosted XML process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-versus-hosted-xml?view=azure-devops-2019)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx), and want to make all fields mandatory in Bug work item.

The first step is to create an inherited process that you can customize. The default, system processes are locked from being customized. Go to **Organization Settings** -- **Process** tab, choose `Create inherited process`.

[image]

Then, add/edit the fields that you want to make them mandatory. On the **Options** tab, indicate if the field is required and specify a default value. Or leave the values blank. By making a field **Required**, users must specify a value for the field to save the work item.

[image]

Link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops